# Copying multiple files in the same directory using a package.json script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, package.json, cp

This works on the command line:

```
cp target/{sitemap.xml,robots.txt} ../fs-dtest-app/
```

But if I put the command inside a script tag in `package.json` like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "c": "cp target/{sitemap.xml,robots.txt} ../fs-dtest-app/"
  },
```

This happens:

```
ole@mkt:~/Temp/dtest/fs-dtest-md$ cp target/{sitemap.xml,robots.txt} ../fs-dtest-app/
ole@mkt:~/Temp/dtest/fs-dtest-md$ npm run c

> @fireflysemantics/fs-dtest-md@1.0.1 c /home/ole/Temp/dtest/fs-dtest-md
> cp target/{sitemap.xml,robots.txt} ../fs-dtest-app/

cp: cannot stat 'target/{sitemap.xml,robots.txt}': No such file or directory
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script) will use the `/bin/sh` [Bourne shell implementation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting) rather than the current interactive shell of a user, whatever that may be (or `cmd.exe` on MS platforms).

In an interactive zsh shell:

```
% echo $0
zsh
```

Running `npm` from the same interactive shell:

```
% npm run shell

> so65660483-npm-shell@1.0.0 shell /so/so65660483-npm-shell
> echo $0

sh
```

[`cp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#cp-invocation) supports copying multiple files without relying on shell globbing in any case:

```
cp target/sitemap.xml target/robots.txt ../fs-dtest-app/
```